# Circle Collider Not Detecting Point Within It

Tags: c++, geometry

In a 2D game, my function is detecting whether a sprite is located within a circles bounds. But, it is failing to do so.

The code below simply loops through all the points that make up the outline of the circle (each point has an x and y coordinate). It then breaks the circle into 4 equally-sized quadrants (like a cartesian plane), and checks whether the sprite is within that quadrant (x/y coordinates start at (0,0) at the top left corner of the window and increase as you go down for y and right for x):

```
bool IsColliding()
{
for (int i = 0; i < TotalPointsThatMakeUpTheCircleOutline; i++)
{
    // Points lining the top left quadrant of circle
    if (Circle.Point[i].xCoordinate <= Circle.getCenterCoordinate().x &&
        Circle.Point[i].yCoordinate <= Circle.getCenterCoordinate().y)
    {
        // Checks if sprite is in-between circle outline point and center point
        if (sprite.xCoordinate >= Circle.Point[i].xCoordinate &&
            sprite.xCoordinate <= Circle.getCenterCoordinate().x &&
            sprite.yCoordinate >= Circle.Point[i].yCoordinate &&
            sprite.yCoordinate <= Circle.getCenterCoordinate().y)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Points lining the top right quadrant of circle
    ........
    // Points lining the bottom left quadrant of circle
    ........
    // Points lining the bottom right quadrant of circle
    ........

    return false;
}
```

}

The other 3 if statements are the same, just reversing appropriate comparison signs ("<" & ">"). Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: You're comparing a y coordinate with an x coordinate.  But this is overly complicated.  You should apply the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: As @1201ProgramAlarm said, this code is kinda crazy.  To test a point within or on a circle all you need to do is test `dx*dx + dy*dy <= r_squared`.    It looks like your collision is trying to do this with each corner of the sprite. Additionally, you might want to test the edge is colliding, even though all corners may be outside the circle.  You could solve that by checking distance of a point (circle centre) from a vector (one edge), and testing the perpendicular is between the edge's two vertices (i.e. the dot-product, which is part of the calculation already, is between 0 and 1).

Answer (score 2):

These "box" tests are actually detecting inside the blue area depicted below, which is a crude approximation of the circle and leaves "holes".

[image]

The test `(Px - Cx)² + (Py - Cy)² ≤ R²` is both fast and perfectly accurate.